# Array sort by value number chars

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting, chars

Hi thinking i have an array like this :

```
[0]=>[
   [0]=>'Hey',
   [1]=>'H',
   [2]=>'He',



]
```

now i would like to sort by number chars and return somenthing like this:

```
[0]=>[
   [0]=>'H',
   [1]=>'He',
   [2]=>'Hey',
]
```

maybe the answer is array_sort() but i'm not able to do that. also i would not like to loop the array to check the number chars of values, but if it's the only way i need to use anyway :P

BTW

how to return this same array ordered by ['name'] key number of chars ASC (h - he -hey -heyh - heyhey )?

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    object(MongoId)#26 (1) {
      ["$id"]=>
      string(24) "4e72858ccaa47ca608030000"
    }
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "h"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    object(MongoId)#29 (1) {
      ["$id"]=>
      string(24) "4e72858ccaa47ca608040000"
    }
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "hey"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    object(MongoId)#31 (1) {
      ["$id"]=>
      string(24) "4e72858ccaa47ca608400000"
    }
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "heyhey"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    object(MongoId)#33 (1) {
      ["$id"]=>
      string(24) "4e72858ccaa47ca6081a0000"
    }
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "he"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    object(MongoId)#35 (1) {
      ["$id"]=>
      string(24) "4e72858ccaa47ca6083d0000"
    }
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "heyh"
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual question? Do you have difficulties because it's a multidimensional array?

Comment: nope i just need to know how to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort by the number of characters, [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) is the way to go. It lets you define your own sorting function.

```
function lengthsort($s1, $s2) {
    if (strlen($s1['name']) < strlen($s2['name'])) {
        return -1;
    } elseif (strlen($s1['name']) > strlen($s2['name'])) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
usort($array, 'lengthsort');
```

Comment: i edited my question cause i need a more deep script i think. thx ;)

Comment: @Ipsuk: the function used by usort will accept elements of your array, so in that function, you can use them as you would an element of your original array. I've updated my example to demonstrate this

Answer (score 2):

PHP's [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) allows you to specify a custom sorting function:

```
<?php
    $arr = array(array('Hey', 'H', 'He'));
    print_r($arr);

    usort($arr[0], function($a, $b) {
        return strlen($a) - strlen($b);
    });

    print_r($arr);
?>
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VhOLu8)

Comment: i edited my question cause i need a more deep script i think. thx ;)

Answer (score 2):

their is no function like array_sort() in php you need to use only sort() function which sorts the array by the values and keep the key information as it is.

$arr = array('0'=>array('0'=>'Hey','1'=>'H','2'=>'He'));

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v):
$arr1 = $v;
sort($arr1);
print_r($arr1);
endforeach;
```

?>

Comment: i edited my question cause i need a more deep script i think. thx ;)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [usort()](https://www.php.net/usort) wich lets you define an own function for sorting:

```
$myarray = array('Hey','H','He');

usort($myarray,function($a, $b){
  if (strlen($a) == strlen($b)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) ? -1 : 1;
});

var_dump($myarray); // array('H','He','Hey')
```

note that i'm using an inline-function here, wich is possible with php 5.3+ - in lower versions of php you'll have to define a traditional function and pass the name of that function to `usort()`

Comment: i edited my question cause i need a more deep script i think. thx ;)